# I have a exploit virus detected by ClamTK that I Can't remove

Tags: malware

I cannot delete or quarantine.

`/usr/share/mime/mime.cache PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_01`

Comment: Have you tried `sudo rm /usr/share/mime/mime.cache PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_01'` What did it say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use clamscan with the option --remove to automatically **remove** all infected file in the scanned folder.

```
clamscan -r --remove /scanned-folder
```

Now to delete your file: you should use  `sudo` with `rm` when deleting some files you don't own:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/share/mime/mime.cache
```